# Storing part of method as another method?

Tags: java, refactoring

Basically, I have code that uses the same few lines in different scenarios, and it makes the code a bit messy (especially since I probably overcomplicated what I made, but that's another issue). What I wanted to do is store that piece of code as another function and calling it in the longer one. WHich should work as far as I know, except, the longer function has variables that aren't set in the shorter one, and if they were, I'm pretty sure it would change the final result of the function.

Here is the longer code:

```
    public static void combat(Character a,Character b){
int battleturn = 1;
int maxTurns=20;
int draw1 = 0;
//stop after 20 turns, or stop when one player has 0 HP.
while (a.health > 0 && b.health > 0 && maxTurns > 0){
    /* run a round of combat*/
    if (b.health < 0.25 * b.maxHealth){
    if (b.getFlee(a)){
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>The enemy has fled successfully<<<<<<<<<<");
        break;
    }else{
        System.out.println("Battle turn " + battleturn + ", <attack> or <flee>?");
        Scanner input = new
        Scanner(System.in);
        String move = input.next();
        while(!move.equals("attack") && !move.equals("flee")){
        System.out.println("Error: Please input <attack> or <flee>.");
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        move = input.next();
        }
        if (move.equals("attack")){
        System.out.println(a.name + " dealt " + a.combatRound(b) + " damage to " + b.name + "." + " Enemy has " 
                   + b.getHealth() + "/" + b.getMaxHealth() + " health.");   
        System.out.println(b.name + " dealt " + b.combatRound(a) + " damage to " + a.name + "." + " You have " +
                   a.getHealth() + "/" + a.getMaxHealth() + " health");
        maxTurns--;
        battleturn++;
        }else if(move.equals("flee")){
        if (a.getFlee(b)){
            draw1++;
            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>You have fled!<<<<<<<<<<");
            break;
        }else{
            System.out.println(a.name + " dealt " + a.combatRound(b) + " damage to " + b.name + "." + " Enemy has " +
                       b.getHealth() + "/" + b.getMaxHealth() + " health.");         
            System.out.println(b.name + " dealt " + b.combatRound(a) + " damage to " + a.name + "." + " You have " +
                       a.getHealth() + "/" + a.getMaxHealth() + " health");  
            maxTurns--;
            battleturn++;
        }
        }
    }

    }else{
    System.out.println("Battle turn " + battleturn + ", <attack> or <flee>?");
    Scanner input = new
        Scanner(System.in);
    String move = input.next();
        while(!move.equals("attack") && !move.equals("flee")){
        System.out.println("Error: Please input <attack> or <flee>.");
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        move = input.next();
    }
    if (move.equals("attack")){
        System.out.println(a.name + " dealt " + a.combatRound(b) + " damage to " + b.name+  "." + " Enemy has " +
                   b.getHealth() + "/" + b.getMaxHealth() + "health.");  
        System.out.println(b.name + " dealt " + b.combatRound(a) + " damage to " + a.name + "." + " You have " +
                   a.getHealth() + "/" + a.getMaxHealth() + " health");  
        maxTurns--;
        battleturn++;
    }else if(move.equals("flee")){
        if (a.getFlee(b)){
        draw1++;
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>You have fled!<<<<<<<<<<");
        break;
        }else{
        System.out.println(a.name + " dealt " + a.combatRound(b) + " damage to " + b.name+ "." + " Enemy has " +
                   b.getHealth() + "/" + b.getMaxHealth() + " health.");     
        System.out.println(b.name + " dealt " + b.combatRound(a) + " damage to " + a.name + "." + " You have " +
                   a.getHealth() + "/" + a.getMaxHealth() + " health");  
        maxTurns--;
        battleturn++;
        }
    }
    }
}
}
```

As you can see there is a part of code that is repeated, and that is.

```
System.out.println("Battle turn " + battleturn + ", <attack> or <flee>?");
        Scanner input = new
        Scanner(System.in);
        String move = input.next();
        while(!move.equals("attack") && !move.equals("flee")){
        System.out.println("Error: Please input <attack> or <flee>.");
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        move = input.next();
        }
        if (move.equals("attack")){
        System.out.println(a.name + " dealt " + a.combatRound(b) + " damage to " + b.name + "." + " Enemy has " 
                   + b.getHealth() + "/" + b.getMaxHealth() + " health.");   
        System.out.println(b.name + " dealt " + b.combatRound(a) + " damage to " + a.name + "." + " You have " +
                   a.getHealth() + "/" + a.getMaxHealth() + " health");
        maxTurns--;
        battleturn++;
        }else if(move.equals("flee")){
        if (a.getFlee(b)){
            draw1++;
            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>You have fled!<<<<<<<<<<");
            break;
        }else{
            System.out.println(a.name + " dealt " + a.combatRound(b) + " damage to " + b.name + "." + " Enemy has " +
                       b.getHealth() + "/" + b.getMaxHealth() + " health.");         
            System.out.println(b.name + " dealt " + b.combatRound(a) + " damage to " + a.name + "." + " You have " +
                       a.getHealth() + "/" + a.getMaxHealth() + " health");  
            maxTurns--;
            battleturn++;
        }
        }
    }
```

It won't compile if I set that chunk of code as a method, because it doesn't have the variables battleturn, maxturns, draw1, but if I put them in there, the amount of battle turns messes up.

Any ideas?

Comment: Proper indentation please

Comment: The best thing would be to break this into smaller bits. Within the while each condition can be turned into a private method. That will help you understand what is going on. If anybody else is going to read your code, it will be extremely time-consuming.

Comment: Sorry about the indentation, I guess I shouldn't have just copied and pasted the code (which looks way better on my screen). I realized that I probably should've done it bit by bit with different methods, but the code does work perfectly well. Although I don't think I can make it more organized without changing this up quite a bit.

Comment: 99% of the code posted is irrelevant to the fundamentals of the question. Please reduce it as much as possible while still retaining its essence - see [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org)

Comment: Good point, might as well delete this and I'll ask it in a bit without all the junk.

Answer (score 0):

Java applications should be modular: each class fulfilling its own function, each method generally performing a single operation.

In a method you can use either class variables or its own local variables.

If you need several methods work with the same data, it should either be part of a class (instance and/or static variables) or passed to each method as parameters.

Make sure that you do not define class variables in a method.  This will create local variables that will *shadow* class variables.

Comment: So do you think making them class variables instead would solve the problem? I'll try it now.

Comment: I just said that it's an option. You business logic dictates the approach.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you accomplish what you're trying to do.

```
private static void reportDamage(Character a,
      Character b) {
    System.out.println(a.name + " dealt "
      + a.combatRound(b) + " damage to " + b.name
      + "." + " Enemy has " + b.getHealth() + "/"
      + b.getMaxHealth() + " health.");
}
```

I suggest changing your combat method like this.

```
int battleturn = 0;
int maxTurns = 20;
// stop after 20 turns, or stop when one player has 0
// HP.
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
try {
  while (a.health > 0 && b.health > 0
      && battleturn < maxturn) {
    battleturn++;
    /* run a round of combat */
    if (b.getFlee(a)) {
      System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>"
          + "The enemy has fled successfully"
          + "<<<<<<<<<<");
      break;
    } else {
      System.out.println("Battle turn "
          + battleturn + ", <attack> or <flee>?");

      boolean isFlee = false;
      boolean isAttack = false;
      String move = input.next();
      for (;;) {
        isAttack = "attack".equalsIgnoreCase(move);
        isFlee = "flee".equalsIgnoreCase(move);
        if (isFlee || isAttack) {
          break;
        }
        System.out.println("Error: "
            + "Please input <attack> or <flee>.");
        move = input.next();
      }
      if (isAttack) {
        reportDamage(a, b);
        reportDamage(b, a);
      } else { // isFlee
        if (a.getFlee(b)) {
          System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>"
              + "You have fled successfully"
              + "<<<<<<<<<<");
          break;
        } else {
          // b is fleeing.
          // reportDamage(a, b);
          reportDamage(b, a);
        }
      }
    }
  }
} finally {
  input.close();
}
```